# Word for common knowledge in a scientific setting?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, writing, science

I remember there being a single word to represent currently accepted facts in a scientific discipline. Common knowledge, but in a scientific setting. It is a jargon-y sounding word.

You'd use it when mentioning an accepted theory or concept that may be unfamiliar to a reader, but is common enough that you don't need to prove or cite it yourself.

The case I'm trying to use it in is like this:

> ...important to note that this study is not on the existence of the bias as it is _______, but rather the failure of subjects to account for it...

I'd like to emphasize that I'm looking for a **single word**. I may be misremembering it, but I am pretty certain there is one word that fits this description.

Comment: This question is similar-ish, but is not a duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241904/expression-for-wrong-common-knowledge-a-set-of-common-misconceptions

Comment: Is this query consistent with Thomas Kuhn's concept of a scientific *paradigm*?

Comment: ... as its existence is established ?

Comment: ...established (citation needed!) fact .... Reviewer #2 will say...

Answer (score 5):

Scientific consensus (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_consensus)):

> the collective judgment, position, and opinion of the community of scientists in a particular field of study.

It also relates to Kuhn's *paradigm shift* which says that a single finding does not change the scientific consensus.

Comment: How would you word the sentence in the question using "scientific consensus?"

Comment: @kirkpatt You could say: *There is scientific consensus that the bias exists [add some references]. This study is not looking to prove the existence of the bias, but for situations when this bias does not hold up. More specifically, ...[add your hypotheses]*

Answer (score 4):

I can’t think of a specifically scientific term, and although the suggestion of @Boondggle is not wrong, the use of the term “consensus” tends to irk me personally. A wording that I would prefer, although one can argue it really isn’t any better, is:

> “it is generally accepted”

or more positively, and without the implication that scientific truth is determined by vote:

> “it is well established”

generally citing a reference to a review of the topic, if possible.

So in the example given in the question I would write:

> ...important to note that this study is not on the existence of the bias — which is well established<sup>ref</sup> — but rather the failure of subjects to account for it...